# How can I segue to a ViewController in another TabController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I'm writing an app with Swift in Xcode, and I'm struggling with 1 thing.

I have a UITabBarController. There are 2 tabs in it, let's say "Home" and "News".

- In the Home tab, there is a Navigation Controller, a bunch of content, some buttons segue to other view controllers within the same tab. Basic stuff.
- In News tab, there is another Navigation Controller, and a TableView showing (you guessed it) a bunch of news. When I tap a news, I segue to a NewsDetails view controller. Also basic stuff.

Now, here comes my issue.
In Home, I display the most recent news, and only this one. Right now, if I tap this News, I segue to the NewsDetails view controller, BUT I'm staying in the Home tab and its own Navigation Controller.
What I'd like to do, is to segue to the NewsDetails, but within the News Tab and within the News Navigation Controller.

To summarize, the behaviour I'm looking for goes as followed: when I click on the most recent news in the Home page, I want to end up within the News tab, looking at the news details. And from there, if I tap the back button, I'm going back to the News tab root, not the Home tab.

I hope I managed to make myself clear enough. Any help, guidance or lead would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to create a subclass of `UITabViewController` and use that. You can implement `prepare(for:sender:)` in the subclass and get a reference to the news navigation controller when the embed segue fires (when the tab bar loads). Then you can use delegation from your home view controller to let the tab bar controller subclass know that it should switch tabs and tell the news view controller to show the appropriate detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if let tabVC = self.tabController {
    tabVC.selectedIndex = 1
    if let navController = tabVC.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        navController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Since you mentioned there are only 2 tabs, so I assume the News is the second tab and hence given the selectedIndex as 1

Also since you are calling this from the Home view controller, we can directly fetch the tab bar using self.tabController. Alternatively you can also use -

```
let tabVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
```

Comment: Hey mate! Thank you so much for your answer, this did the trick, although I had to change the way the NewsDetailViewController is instanciated. Instead of "let vc = UIViewController()", I had to do "let vc:NewsDetailViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsDetail") as! NewsDetailViewController;"

Cheers!